# SQL Server 2008 - SQL Mail and sender addres

Tags: sql-server, smtp

is there possibility to have procedure which sents emails from SQL Server 2008 where I can type sender e-mail address?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2008 use [Database Mail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx), not [SQL Mail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191207.aspx) to send email.  SQL Mail is legacy & will be removed in future versions.

You will first need to [configure Database Mail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/dd939167.aspx)

Once a profile has been setup for Database Mail, use the `sp_send_dbmail` [stored procedure.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)

**EDIT:**

It works fine for me when i use a different `@from_address` from what is specified as the email address in the profile.  This address is only used when i don't specify a from_address.  Code I used to send the email is below:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name='nick '
, @from_address ='Nick Kavadias <nick.kavadias@example.com>'
, @recipients='other_address@example.com'
, @subject='this is a test message'
, @body='t.e.s.t m.e.s.s.a.g.e'
```

A screen shot of my mail profile settings are below:

[alt text http://img91.yfrog.com/img91/1298/databasemail.jpg](http://img91.yfrog.com/img91/1298/databasemail.jpg)

Is the mail being queued? Do you have any logs from your SMTP server?

Check that there aren't any error in the database mail log table `msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log`

Failing that, check that it's not something the mail server is disallowing.

Comment: You are right. But this procedure is not allowing to give sender e-mail or reply to address.

I want to achieve this by not adding new e-mail account to Database Mail when every time I want to use different sender e-mail address (or reply to). Is this possible?

Comment: database mail is working as expected.  I've updated my post